# Having trouble migrating from sql 2000 to sql 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration, upgrade, sql-server-2000

1. I have an old 32-bit application sitting on a sql server 2000 personal edition windows NT 6.0 service pack 2.
2. I am performing a side-by-side migration
3. I was given a windows 2016 x64.
4. I installed SQL Server 2008 developer edition x86
5. I backed-up and restored the necessary databases, changed compatibility level, move logins and permissions, move over necessary extended stored procedures.

ISSUE: The application throws an error when trying to connect. 'Could not load the DLL C:\Program Files (x86)...applicationspecified.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 126(The specified module could not be found.)'

I did check to confirm the path is correct.
I used dependency walker to see if there were any missing DLLs

EDIT: The app was installed on the new windows server (2016), opening the app while on windows 2016 against old database/sql2000 works fine. Opening the app against the new databases/sql2008 fails.

Comment: You realize 2008 will not be supported after July 2019?   Feels like you are missing an opportunity

Comment: @JohnCappelletti my end goal is to put it on 2012 if possible

Comment: What application throws the error?

Comment: @user10609312 Any particular reason you don't want to go for an even newer version?

Comment: @TimMylott it was a third party application used for reporting, the company no longer exists.

Comment: @Dason I do not know how far I can push the application compatibility.

Comment: You are upgrading from one dead version to another. You should upgrade to a currently supported system. And since you have 64bit OS why do you want to connect to a 32bit database?

Comment: @SeanLange the original databases were 32bit

Comment: I'm not sure what this question has to do with SQL Server, to be honest.

Comment: So what? Time to upgrade. You don't have to keep your databases 32bit just because they were in the old system.

Comment: that error seems more related to the third party app and not related to sql-server.  I'd maybe start by tracking down the original install for the application.  If you don't have it, try manually registering the DLLs I suppose or running the exe in a different compatibility mode.

Comment: @pmbAustin I have very limited experience with sql server 2000, although the error says it cant load the dll. My experience with sql server is that error messages are not always the actual problem. I was hoping someone would have some insight about the migration behavior from 2000 to 2008, in case i missed something along the way, or if they've come across similar situation

Comment: Somehow you have a way to change the connection used by the application, correct? So what values did you use to configure the connection to the newer instance?

Comment: And just to verify - "works fine in the new OS/old instance" means you actually did some level of testing to validate it. Just trying to rule out the fact that you might assume "can connect" implies "works correctly across all the functionality that app offers".

Comment: @SMor yes, i ran some reports via the app and it gave the necessary results. Opening the application prompts for login and server/instance name. That is how it connects.It looks for the database from there

Comment: Unfortunately you need to know HOW it connects to an instance. What technology is used - ODBC? DBLib? If i remember correctly, dblib is still supported but MS stopped shipping the needed DLLs to use it at some point. Is this a default / named instance issue? Do you happen to know what language or dev environment was used?